# Elasticsearch past version document

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to maintain last 2 versions of documents in Elasticsearch.

I created, for example, first update for product123

```
 PUT /products/_doc/product123
   { "name" : "toothPaste",
     "price" : 10
    }
```

Then for second update product123:

```
  PUT /products/_doc/product123
    {
    "name" : "toothPaste",
    "price" : 12
    }
```

When I query using GET API - I am getting  `"price": 12` - Current Version

Is it possible that I will get `"price": 10` (Last Version) of the same index

Comment: No you can't acheive that since you're updating that document in the later call

Comment: Maybe you should do it in another way where you could provide a version in the id, something like `PUT /products/_doc/product123_v1` and the later one `PUT /products/_doc/product123_v2` and for query to can do `GET /products/_doc/product123*`, will that help?

Answer (score 1):

the only way to do this in Elasticsearch is to manage it yourself, as any updates applied to a document do not retain the previous version

you could do this using separate documents as MAZux mentioned above, or you could do it in different fields, eg `price` and `previous_price`